# Creating a draggable division inside another div

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to create a draggable div which is inside a bigger div.
This is my program. But Its not working.
I guess the draggable function is the one to use make a div draggable.
also which version I have to use? 1.7.2 or 1.3.2 ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>First jQuery-Enabled Page</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #draggable {
                background-color:blue;
                width: 150px;
                height: 150px;
                padding: 0.5em;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

                $("#draggable").draggable();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="draggable">
            <p>hai</p>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to modify your code and produce a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mUa3r/

Essentially to have your box draggable and bound by a container, use `{containment: parent}`, as described [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment).

Update: (since the link wasn't working for you)

**Script:**

```
    <script>
            $(function() {
            $("#draggable").draggable({containment: "parent" });
    });
    </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="container">
            <div id="draggable">
                    <p>hai</p>
            </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    #container {background-color:grey; width: 300px; height: 300px;}
    #draggable {background-color:blue; width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em;}​
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I recon your javascript should be as follows;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

       $("#draggable").draggable();

    });

 </script>
```

Hope this helps